# Filtering 1st relationship by 2nd relationship

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm struggling to filter teachers belonging to a school by a teacher relationship.

Schools have users. Users may have polymorphic relationship to teachers
[this works so far].

...then teachers have one or more teachingstages and teachingsubjects that I'd like to filter by one or more (passing arrays of IDs).

```
$teachers = $school->teachers()
                ->whereHas('teachingstages', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                    $query->whereIn('teachingstage_id', $filters['teachingstages']);
                })
                ->whereHas('teachingsubjects', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                    $query->whereIn('teachingsubject_id', $filters['teachingsubjects']);
                })
            ->orderBy('rating', 'desc')->get();
```

Currently I do get results but a teacher with multiple teachingstages and teachingsubjects are excluded. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks K...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the above does work as I intended. Apologies, there was a very minor issue with the seeding of the data which is why I was getting unexpected results :/ my bad - thanks for looking though...